# output 10 with memory_order_seq_cst

Tags: c++, multithreading, memory-barriers, stdatomic, lockless

When i run this program i get output as 10 which seems to be impossible for me. I'm running this on x86_64 core i3 ubuntu.

If the output is 10, then 1 must have come from either c or d.

Also in thread t[0], we assign c as 1. Now a is 1 since it occurs before c=1. c is equal to b which was set to 1 by thread 1. So when we store d it should be 1 as a=1.

---

- Can output 10 happen with memory_order_seq_cst ? I tried inserting a atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst) on both thread between 1st (variable =1 ) and 2nd line (printf) but it still didn't work.

Uncommenting both the **fence** doesn't work.
Tried running with **g++** and **clang++**. Both give the same result.

```
#include<thread>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<cstdio>
#include<atomic>
using namespace std;

atomic<int> a,b,c,d;

void foo(){
        a.store(1,memory_order_seq_cst);
//        atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst);
        c.store(b,memory_order_seq_cst);
}

void bar(){
        b.store(1,memory_order_seq_cst);
  //      atomic_thread_fence(memory_order_seq_cst);
        d.store(a,memory_order_seq_cst);
}

int main(){
        thread t[2];
        t[0]=thread(foo); t[1]=thread(bar);
        t[0].join();t[1].join();
        printf("%d%d\n",c.load(memory_order_seq_cst),d.load(memory_order_seq_cst));
}
```

```
bash$ while [ true ]; do ./a.out | grep "10" ; done 
10
10
10
10
```

Comment: Did you debug / set breakpoints and single stepped?

Comment: @StureS it a threading question, setting breakpoints and stepping changes the behaviour of the program.

Comment: That should give you a clue where the problem is. See the answer from Dani below.

Comment: Why would `memory_order_seq_cst` prevent the code from executing whole `bar()` before starting to execute `foo()`? In that case, your output would be correct. While `c.store` certainly happens after `a.store`, I don't think `memory_order_seq_cst` guarantees the order of calling those two whole functions.

Comment: @RichardCritten: To be fair, setting breakpoints and single-stepping each thread separately can let you explore possible orderings.  But not runtime *re*ordering effects of store buffers and multiple requests in flight; single stepping is so slow that each asm operation is effectively seq_cst, after the compiler has nailed down whatever compile-time ordering it chose.  It can be a useful technique to sanity check a design for something like a lockless queue, but probably not for something like this.  (Although everything is already seq_cst so maybe)

Comment: @nvn: your text description is still talking about printfs inside each thread function, not after both join.  Either way would be equivalent if you'd printed `d=%d\n` or whatever; this way does make it unambiguous which number comes from which var.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

10 (c=1, d=0) is easily explained: `bar` happened to run first, and finished before `foo` read `b`.

Quirks of inter-core communication to get threads started on different cores means it's easily possible for this to happen even though `thread(foo)` ran first in the main thread.  e.g. maybe an interrupt arrived at the core the OS chose for `foo`, delaying it from actually getting into that code<sup>1</sup>.

**Remember that seq_cst only guarantees that some total order exists for all seq_cst operations which is compatible with the sequenced-before order within each thread**. (And any other happens-before relationship established by other factors). So the following order of atomic operations is possible without even breaking out the `a.load`<sup>2</sup> in bar separately from the `d.store` of the resulting int temporary.

```
        b.store(1,memory_order_seq_cst);   // bar1.  b=1
        d.store(a,memory_order_seq_cst);   // bar2.  a.load reads 0, d=0

        a.store(1,memory_order_seq_cst);   // foo1
        c.store(b,memory_order_seq_cst);   // foo2.  b.load reads 1, c=1
// final: c=1, d=0
```

**`atomic_thread_fence(seq_cst)` has no impact anywhere because all your operations are already `seq_cst`.**  A fence basically just stops reordering of this thread's operations; it doesn't wait for or sync with fences in other threads.

(Only a load that sees a value stored by another thread can create synchronization.  But such a load doesn't *wait* for the other store; it has no way of knowing there is another store.  If you want to keep loading until you see the value you expect, you have to write a spin-wait loop.)

---

Footnote 1:
Since all your atomic vars are probably in the same cache line, even if execution did reach the top of `foo` and `bar` at the same time on two different cores, false-sharing is likely going to let both operations from one thread happen while the other core is still waiting to get exclusive ownership.  Although seq_cst stores are slow enough (on x86 at least) that hardware fairness stuff might relinquish exclusive ownership after committing the first store of `1`.  Anyway, lots of ways for both operations in one thread to happen before the other thread and get 10 or 01.  **Even possible to get `11`** if we get `b=1` then `a=1` before either load.  Using seq_cst does stop the hardware from doing the load early (before the store is globally visible), so it's very possible.

Footnote 2: The lvalue-to-rvalue evaluation of bare `a` uses the overloaded `(int)` conversion which is equivalent to `a.load(seq_cst)`.  The operations from `foo` *could* happen between that load and the `d.store` that gets a temporary value from it.  `d.store(a)` is not an atomic copy; it's equivalent to `int tmp = a;` `d.store(tmp);`.  That isn't necessary to explain your observations.

Comment: a,b,c,d are all atomic. if d.store(a) is not atomic copy , what should i use to make it atomic ? Can you be a bit detailed ?

Comment: @nvn: What you have is an atomic load, and a *separate* atomic store. C++11 (and most hardware) doesn't have 2-operand atomic instructions, so you can't make it an atomic copy, except by using a lock / mutex to disallow any other thread *observing* non-atomicity.  Or on a few ISAs, like some versions of m68k, there is hardware support for an operation like [DCAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double_compare-and-swap) that is an atomic RMW on 2 non-contiguous memory operations at once, but C++ doesn't expose it, otherwise almost all implementations would need `.is_lock_free() == false`.

Comment: @nvn: Or on some modern CPUs, you can use transactional memory to make a read + a write into a single transaction.  (e.g. Intel TSX if it's not disabled for security (info leak side channels) errata reasons.)  Of course, in most use cases there's no need for this, and most observers wouldn't be able to tell the difference between separately-atomic load and store vs. a single atomic transaction.

Answer (score 0):

The printf statements are unsynchronized so output of 10 can be just a reordered 01.
01 happens when the functions before the printf run serially.

Comment: I don't think it is due to printf. So i removed the printf and please look at the updated program where i store the values in atomic variables and print them after joining both the threads.